# Storing and retrieving images in sql server 2005 in asp.net via c#

Tags: asp.net

How do I store and retrieve images in sql server 2005 in asp.net with c#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may store them as binary data.
You may write a module (derived from IHttpModule), register it for RequestBegin event.
When request come you may retrieve data from database, store it on disk with requested file name and 
this image will automatically be returned by built-in IIS handler (which is written in native code and works very fast).

Comment: could you provide me with an example?

Comment: @Chandan I'm pretty sure you should be able to figure it out with the steps that Tony provided. If you can't then I don't think you really know enough about Asp.Net to get much out of an example.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/Store_images_in_SQL_Serve.aspx) is a project that does just the thing.  All you need to do is move the storing and retrieving logic into your ASP .Net application.

Comment: There is no function like FromStream in Image class

using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageData, 0, imageData.Length))
        {
            ms.Write(imageData, 0, imageData.Length);

            //Set image variable value using memory stream.
            newImage = Image.FromStream(ms, true);
        }

Comment: System.Drawing.Image definitely has the FromStream method.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.fromstream.aspx

Comment: My friend what you are talking about is in windows application and not in web applications

Comment: I understand what I am talking about.  All you need to do is alter the application to work with your ASP .Net application.  This is straight forward enough.

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended.

Best practice is storing meta-data (here meta-data is you image file name) inside database and sotre them on file-system (for example c:\images). Then when you need an image you can ask database for its name and retreive it from file-system.

This helps you to have a compact database and maintenance became easy. Handling large databases backup/restore is a headache.